# how do i convert my pygame games to executable

Tags: pygame

I have a lot of python games I made in pygame and want to compile them so I can distribute them on sites like itch.io and gamejolt.com, the thing is, when I try to my executable game it says "fatal error detected" and "failed to execute script Pong". I was using pyinstaller to create a standalone file.

Comment: It doesn't look like we have enough information here to diagnose what's going wrong in your Pong script. Can you please edit your question to include a minimal complete verifiable example we can use to reproduce the problem you're observing?